# How do I typeset a tenfold powering (a tower-of-powers) with LaTeX?

Tags: superscripts

How do I write `x^x^x^x^x^x^x^x^x^x`?

My LaTeX distribution doesn't wanna eat it, it stops swallowing stuff at the double power x^x^x.
What I'm aiming at is essentially building a telescope out of X's stacked on top of each other. Don't ask, that's my sense of humour.

Comment: `$x^{\scriptscriptstyle x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x}}}}}}}}}$`

Comment: I'm surprised noone has said `\(x\uparrow\uparrow10\)` just because.

Comment: @You It would in fact only be `$x \uparrow 10$`; two `\uparrow`s and you would have `x \uparrow 10` exponentiation steps.  (But this is almost entirely beside the point. `:)`)

Comment: According to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html, you would need two arrows.

Comment: LaTeX vs. Viagra.

Comment: @Arian as a CS major, it's an off-by-one error.  As a math major, *I'm ashamed*.

Answer (score 69):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\powertower#1#2{#1\ifnum#2>1 ^{\powertower{#1}{\numexpr#2-1\relax}}\fi}

\begin{document}

$\powertower{x}{100}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the TeX version of *Stairway to heaven*. `:)` Amazing!

Comment: @PauloCereda: maybe so, but that x at the bottom left is obviously under a lot of stress, and ready to fall over at any moment.

Comment: @wasteofspace: I think David is inspired because we were singing *The London bridge is falling down* [in the chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12106301#12106301) yesterday. `:)`

Comment: Disclaimer: I apologize for inadvertently adding *The* before *London bridge*. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda a minor sin compared to your earlier one of referencing a picture of tower bridge to accompany the lyrics

Comment: @David: Hey, blame the YouTube video! `:)` And what if Tower bridge is falling down too? `:)`

Comment: Hey it has a limit of 254! What if I need 256?

Comment: @NictraSavios see http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12126469#12126469

Comment: You could have called this macro `\towerofpower` in honor of a [certain soul/funk band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Power). :-)

Comment: You're aggregating `\numexpr...\relax` pairs in your `\powertower`, you could as well use `\def\powertower#1#2{#1\ifnum\numexpr#2>1 ^{\powertower{#1}{#2-1}}\fi}`, or you evaluate `\numexpr` before passing it on to the next recursion.

Answer (score 35):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\[ x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}}}}}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm curious—how hard would it be to generalize this as a `\PowerTower{x}{10}` ([power tower reference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html))

Comment: @Sean: done. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Yay!!

Answer (score 29):

<sub>I dedicate this code to Sean. `:)`</sub>

Long live `expl3`! `:)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \paulo_epicrecursion:nn #1 #2 {
   #1^{ \int_compare:nTF { #2 > 1 } { 
      \paulo_epicrecursion:nn { #1 } { \int_eval:n { #2 - 1 } }
   } {
     #1
   } }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{ \powertower } { m m } {
    \paulo_epicrecursion:nn { #1 } { #2 }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\powertower{x}{10}$

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Quack]

**Update:** egreg brilliantly noted that the above code generates a long list of nested `\int_eval:n` calls. The optimization is presented as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \paulo_epicrecursion:nn #1 #2
  {
   #1^{
     \int_compare:nTF { #2 > 1 }
      { \paulo_epicrecursion:nx { #1 } { \int_eval:n { #2 - 1 } } }
      { #1 }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{ \powertower } { m m }
 {
  \paulo_epicrecursion:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \paulo_epicrecursion:nn { nx }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\powertower{x}{10}$

\end{document}
```

The trick here is the generated variant. As egreg explained, the first call doesn't need the full expansion, but the recursive ones do.

Comment: +1 for `\powertower` and `epicrecursion`. (Edit: Ah, I saw Sean's comment only after writing this one.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: `:)`

Comment: superb, absolutely superb :)

Comment: The command name is wrong: it should be `\paulo_epicrecursion:nn` because it has *two* arguments.

Comment: @egreg: oopsie, I forgot to update it when I added the second argument. Thanks, fixed. `:)`

Comment: Wouldn't `\paulo_epicrecursion:nn { #1 } { #2 - 1 }` suffice? `\int_compare:nTF { #2 > 1 }` should evaluate `#2` by itself. (Maybe then `\int_compare:nTF { (#2) > 1 }` just to be safe. :)

Comment: I'm touched `:')` The recursion is strong with this one.

Comment: @cgnieder: I actually have absolutely no idea. `:)`

Answer (score 28):

Here's a shorter version with LaTeX3 functions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{ \powertower } { m m }
 {
  #1
  \prg_replicate:nn { #2 - 1 } { ^\c_group_begin_token #1 }
  \prg_replicate:nn { #2 - 1 } { \c_group_end_token }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\powertower{x}{10}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Limitation: the tower maximum size is 254 because of the maximum nested group level is 255. This limitation on the nested groups is also in the other solutions, of course. Here's a picture of `$\powertower{x}{253}$` (I was trying with `standalone` that adds a level of grouping and forgot to change).

With LuaLaTeX the limit is pushed to 499; at 500 the semantic nest size is overflown.

[image]

Comment: As always, brilliant! `:)`

Comment: Very elegant; it's the simpler solutions that seem to be harder to think of, sometimes. `:)`

Answer (score 21):

What? afraid of going beyond `255`? not me!

[image: epictower1]

This was obtained as `$\epictower{x}{600}$`.

> This reproduces *exactly* what `TeX` would have done (were it not for
>   the limitation to 255 group levels) inclusive of a quite odd feature
>   of `TeX` regarding extra horizontal space on the right.
>
> *update 2015. I forgot to say in 2013 what I was referring too: the
>   horizontal whitespace extending to the the right of the power towers,
>   on the side of the character glyphs. The image with the 600 x's does
>   not show the resulting (big) extra horizontal space because the figure
>   was clipped to the contained ink. The images below with shorter
>   staircases display using fboxes the extra whitespace, look on right of
>   the rightmost characters the distance to the fbox frame. You can also
>   experiment with David Carlisle's macro inside an fbox (with
>   `\fboxsep=0pt` or rather `-0.4pt`).*
>
> [image: epictower2]

In the next picture, on top left what is produced by `\epictower`, on the right and bottom the original thing, to demonstrate that horizontal and vertical placement is correct (the font size is set to `60pt` and then standard size).

> [image: epictowerx]
>
> [image: epictower3]
>   [image: epictowersmallx]
>   [image: epictowersmallX]

And here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
% use this for 600 x's!
% \usepackage [paperheight=65cm,paperwidth=100cm]{geometry}
\usepackage {geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\makeatletter
\newdimen \epic@x
\newdimen \epic@y
\newdimen \epic@extrax
\newdimen \epic@extray
\newbox \epic@one
\newbox \epic@two
\newcommand{\epictower}[2]{\ifcase #2\relax
         1\or #1\or {#1}^{#1}\or {#1}^{{#1}^{#1}}\else \epic@tower {#1}{#2}\fi }
\def\epic@tower #1#2{%
    \sbox\epic@one{\m@th $\scriptscriptstyle #1$}%
    \sbox\epic@two{\m@th $\scriptscriptstyle {#1}^{#1}$}%
    \epic@x=\wd\epic@one 
    \epic@extrax=\wd\epic@two
    \advance\epic@extrax by -\epic@x
    \advance\epic@extrax by -\epic@x
    \epic@y=\ht\epic@two
    \advance\epic@y by -\ht\epic@one
    \epic@extray=\ht\epic@one
    \advance\epic@extray by -\epic@y
    \toks@ \expandafter{\the\numexpr #2-3}%
    {#1}^{{#1}^{%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1sp}%
    \begin{picture}({\numexpr (#2-2)*\epic@x+(#2-3)*\epic@extrax\relax},%
                    {\numexpr (#2-2)*\epic@y+\epic@extray\relax})
    \count@\z@
    \loop
        \put (\numexpr \count@ * \epic@x\relax,%
              \numexpr \count@ * \epic@y\relax){\copy\epic@one}%
    \ifnum\the\toks@>\count@
    \advance\count@ \@ne
    \repeat
    \end{picture}}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\fboxsep-.4pt
\fontsize{60}{60}

\newcommand{\testtexpowers}[1]{%
\setbox 1 \hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle #1$}%
\setbox 2 \hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle #1^{\fbox{\copy1}}$}%
\setbox 3 \hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle #1^{#1^{\fbox{\copy1}}}$}%
\setbox 4 \hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle #1^{#1^{#1^{\fbox{\copy1}}}}$}%
\setbox 5 \hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle #1^{#1^{#1^{#1^{\fbox{\copy1}}}}}$}%
\setbox 6 \hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle #1^{#1^{#1^{#1^{#1^{\fbox{\copy1}}}}}}$}%
\setbox 7 \hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle #1^{#1^{#1^{#1^{#1^{#1^{\fbox{\copy1}}}}}}}$}%
\setbox 8 \hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle #1^{#1^{#1^{#1^{#1^{#1^{#1^{\fbox{\copy1}}}}}}}}$}%
\setbox 9 \hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle #1^{#1^{#1^{#1^{#1^{#1^{#1^{#1^{\fbox{\copy1}}}}}}}}}$}%
\leavevmode\rlap{\rlap{\rlap{\rlap{\rlap{\rlap{\rlap{\rlap{\fbox{\box1}}\fbox{\box2}}\fbox{\box3}}\fbox{\box4}}\fbox{\box5}}\fbox{\box6}}\fbox{\box7}}\fbox{\box8}}\fbox{\box9}}

\testtexpowers{x}

\testtexpowers{X}

\testtexpowers{xX}

\clearpage

\fbox{$\epictower {x}{1}$}\fbox{$x$}\hrule\fbox{$x$}
\hrule
\fbox{$\epictower {x}{2}$}\fbox{$x^x$}\hrule\fbox{$x^x$}
\hrule
\fbox{$\epictower {x}{3}$}\fbox{$x^{x^x}$}\hrule\fbox{$x^{x^x}$}
\hrule
\fbox{$\epictower {x}{4}$}\fbox{$x^{x^{x^x}}$}\hrule\fbox{$x^{x^{x^x}}$}
\hrule
\fbox{$\epictower {x}{5}$}\fbox{$x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}$}\hrule\fbox{$x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}$}
\hrule
\fbox{$\epictower {x}{6}$}\fbox{$x^{x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}}$}\hrule\fbox{$x^{x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}}$}
\hrule



\clearpage

\fbox{$\epictower {X}{1}$}\fbox{$X$}\hrule\fbox{$X$}
\hrule
\fbox{$\epictower {X}{2}$}\fbox{$X^X$}\hrule\fbox{$X^X$}
\hrule
\fbox{$\epictower {X}{3}$}\fbox{$X^{X^X}$}\hrule\fbox{$X^{X^X}$}
\hrule
\fbox{$\epictower {X}{4}$}\fbox{$X^{X^{X^X}}$}\hrule\fbox{$X^{X^{X^X}}$}
\hrule
\fbox{$\epictower {X}{5}$}\fbox{$X^{X^{X^{X^X}}}$}\hrule\fbox{$X^{X^{X^{X^X}}}$}
\hrule
\fbox{$\epictower {X}{6}$}\fbox{$X^{X^{X^{X^{X^X}}}}$}\hrule\fbox{$X^{X^{X^{X^{X^X}}}}$}
\hrule

\end{document}

% comment-out the preceding, sets page dimensions in geometry
% only limited by TeX's \maxdimen !

$\epictower{x}{600}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: it is easy to modify `\epictower` to print the exponents along an arbitrary algebraically parametrized curve, for nice special effects. Size of the bounding box will need extra coding if the curve zig-zags; or one may just set the bounding box to the space taken by `x^{x^x}` for simplicity.

Answer (score 11):

As more than three powers get very unpleasant to read, I would really recommend using another notation. As already proposed in the comments (hence a community wiki answer), you can represent power towers by the [arrow notation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html):

```
(x\uparrow\uparrow10)
```

[image]

You might want to watch [Numberphiles YouTube video about Grahams number](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTeJ64KD5cg) to understand this notation.

This notation is much easier to read. In fact, you can read it at all in contrast to the big tower of powers notation.

Comment: The recursion: this notation was introduced by Someone that is already a legend...`=)`.

Answer (score 7):

This is a version of David's answer, but without fancy `etex` for those being stuck with Knuth TeX.

```
\newcount\powercount
\def\powertower#1#2{
  #1\powercount=#2
  \advance\powercount by -1
  \ifnum\powercount>1
  ^{\powertower{#1}{\the\powercount}}
  \fi
}
$\powertower{x}{100}$
\bye
```

> [image]