# N-level nested nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nesting

I read this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40234/tikz-a-big-box-with-fixed-width-containing-smaller-boxes) but I didn't get how to repeat the process more than one time. I make an example: I'd like to have a big green box which contains two copies of the light blue box presented in the other question. It, again, contains the blue boxes with the numbers.

I'm starting with this

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0.05cm,node distance=0.8cm,]
\tikzstyle{bigbox} = [draw=blue!50, thick, fill=blue!10, rounded corners, rectangle]
\tikzstyle{box} = [minimum size=0.6cm, rounded corners,rectangle, fill=blue!50]
%
\node[box] (11) {1};
\node[box,right of=11] (12) {2};
\node[box,right of=12] (13) {3};
\node[box,below of=11] (21) {4};
\node[box,right of=21] (22) {5};
\node[box,right of=22] (23) {6};
%
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \node[bigbox] [fit = (11) (23)] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175850/macro-evaluating-number-of-arguments-without-limitation

Answer (score 2):

Easy job with `matrix` library:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,matrix}
\tikzset{
   bigbox/.style = {draw=blue!50, thick, fill=blue!10, rounded corners, rectangle},
   box/.style = {minimum size=0.6cm, rounded corners,rectangle, fill=blue!50},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0.05cm,node distance=0.8cm]
   \matrix (a)[row sep=2mm, column sep=2mm, inner sep=2mm, bigbox, matrix of nodes, every node/.style=box]
      {
        1 & 2 & 3\\
        4 & 5 & 6\\
        };
\matrix (b)[row sep=2mm, column sep=2mm, inner sep=2mm, bigbox, matrix of nodes,
        every node/.style=box,anchor=west] at (a.east) {
            1 & 2 & 3\\
            4 & 5 & 6\\
        };
%
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \node[bigbox,draw=green,fill=green!10]  [fit = (a) (b)] (A)  {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to increase the sepration between two blue boxes use this:

```
\matrix (b)[row sep=2mm, column sep=2mm, inner sep=2mm, bigbox, matrix of nodes,
        every node/.style=box] at ([xshift=2cm]a.east) {
            1 & 2 & 3\\
            4 & 5 & 6\\
        };
```

[image]

Change `xshift` suitably.

Comment: Ok, next step. Add one more box level. How to add a red box surrounding the blue ones each? That's my problem. The use of pgfonlayer to create the bigger box. If I avoid that and I understand how to nest N levels I can do my job easily, even for the future!
Thanks however for the current reply. :)

Comment: @usernumberone If you reveal a final picture of what you intend to have, it will be useful (instead of just saying n-levels) Is it like the one as posted by Ignasi? You are asking x but want to do y ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As Harish explained, a `matrix` offers two layers (inside nodes and matrix) but both are drawn on `main` (default) layer. `backgrounds` library introduces two more layers `background` and `foreground`. But if you need more layers you can define them with `\pgfdeclarelayer` and once declared order them with `\pgfsetlayers` command.

Next code based on Harish example shows how to use both commands.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,matrix}
\tikzset{
   bigbox/.style = {draw=blue!50, thick, fill=blue!10, rounded corners, rectangle},
   box/.style = {minimum size=0.6cm, rounded corners,rectangle, fill=blue!50},
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfdeclarelayer{minusone}
\pgfdeclarelayer{minustwo}
\pgfdeclarelayer{minusthree}
\pgfsetlayers{minusthree,minustwo,minusone,background,main,foreground}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0.05cm,node distance=0.8cm]
   \matrix (a)[row sep=2mm, column sep=2mm, inner sep=2mm, bigbox, matrix of nodes, every node/.style=box]
      {
        1 & 2 & 3\\
        4 & 5 & 6\\
        };
\matrix (b)[row sep=2mm, column sep=2mm, inner sep=2mm, bigbox, matrix of nodes,
        every node/.style=box,anchor=west] at ([xshift=2cm]a.east) {
            1 & 2 & 3\\
            4 & 5 & 6\\
        };
%

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \node[bigbox,draw=red,fill=red!10]  [fit = (a)] (A)  {};
        \node[bigbox,draw=red,fill=red!10]  [fit = (b)] (B)  {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{minusone}
        \node[bigbox,draw=green,fill=green!10]  [fit = (A) (B)] (AB)  {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
%

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{minustwo}
        \node[bigbox,draw=purple,fill=purple!10]  [fit = (AB)] (AB-1)  {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
        \node[bigbox,draw=orange,fill=orange!10,opacity=.5]  [fit = (a-2-2.west|-AB-1.south) (b-1-2.east|-AB-1.north)] (AB-2)  {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{minusthree}
        \node[bigbox,draw=brown,fill=brown!10]  [fit = (AB-2) (AB-1)] (AB-3)  {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]