# How do I use multiple superscripts (super, super-super, super-super-super, etc) with them all smaller than each other?

Tags: math-mode, superscripts, size

I wonder how to make every superscript level smaller than each other.

Like, `2^{2^{2^{2^{2^{2^{2}}}}}}` makes the *first* superscript smaller, but the rest of the superscripts the same size as the first one.

I have done this first on [wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula) but ***of course*** it doesn't go like I want it to go like.

Comment: Welcome! I assume the underlying point here is that stuff can only usefully be made so small. After that, making it smaller just makes it illegible and no longer helps to clarify the meaning.

Comment: This ought to be a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144490/how-do-i-typeset-a-tenfold-powering-a-tower-of-powers-with-latex/144525#144525 but you ask that things keep getting smaller, but you shouldn't want that:-)

Comment: If it really is just `2`s, you could always use *up-arrrow notation* ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth's_up-arrow_notation ), which avoids the readability problem entirely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `\scalebox` command from the `graphicx` package and make a macro that does this.  But, as mentioned by @cfr in the comments to your question, readability very quickly becomes an issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\aesuper[2][0.90]{^{\scalebox{#1}{$\scriptstyle#2$}}}

\begin{document}

\[
  2\aesuper[1]{2\aesuper{2\aesuper{2\aesuper{2\aesuper{2\aesuper{2}}}}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Or `\resizebox` of the same package  `graphicx` ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newdimen\antes
\setlength{\antes}{4em}
\gdef\mb#1{\resizebox{\antes}{!}{#1%
\global\addtolength{\antes}{-.15\antes}}}
\begin{document}
 $\mb{2}^{\mb{2}^{\mb{2}^{\mb{2}^{\mb{2}^{\mb{2}^{%
\mb{2}^{\mb{2}^{\mb{2}^{\mb{2}^{\mb{2}}}}}}}}}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Note that `\global\addtolength` doesn't work if `calc` is loaded.

Comment: @egreg Good to know. I tested that `\dimexpr`  work here  (for example, `\dimexpr-.15\antes-.6em` to produce a nice mirror effect) but  I was not aware of  packages  as `calc`  or `pgf` .